# What are the Minecraft weather commands and how do they work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My son loves the weather and he would like to use these commands to alter the weather. However, he's tried but nothing seems to work.

How do we use the weather and wm commands?

Comment: While these questions are slightly different, the answer to the duplicate explains how the `/weather` command works and therefore answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure cheats are turned on. Changing the weather in a normal world can give you an advantage, so it is not normally allowed.

The command structure for the weather command is `/weather clear/rain/thunder {optional duration}`